# Loop Google sheet - returns only last row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know why when this function runs it only exports the last row of the feed array?

This is the snippet I am stuck on, the 'j' it iterating fine but the value I set on the 'messExSheet' is always the last row.

```
msgObj[curCol].push(curCel)
messString = JSON.stringify(msgObj);
messExSheet.getRange(j, 1).setValue(messString);
```

Looking to get the first row, and using it as an object key like below

```
var Row_1 = ['r1-c1', 'r1-c2', 'r1-c3'];
var Row_2 = ['r2-c1', 'r2-c2', 'r2-c3'];
var Row_3 = ['r3-c1', 'r3-c2', 'r3-c3'];

//Out put
[{"r1-c1":["r2-c1"]}, {"r1-c2":["r2-c2"]}, {"r1-c3":["r2-c3"]}]
[{"r1-c1":["r3-c1"]}, {"r1-c2":["r3-c2"]}, {"r1-c3":["r3-c3"]}]
```

Full function below

```
----------

function messageToJSON(){

  var sheetName = 'sheet';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();

  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, lastRow, lastColumn)
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();

  var messExSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var messExShName = 'messageExport';
  var messExSheet = messExSs.getSheetByName(messExShName);

  var msgObj = {};
  var result = [];
  var curCel = [];
  var messString = '';

  for ( i = 0; i < lastColumn; i++){ // columes ➔
    var curCol = rangeValues[0][i];
    msgObj[curCol] = [];

    for (j = 1 ; j < lastRow; j++){ // rows ⬇︎ //
      msgObj[curCol] = [];
      curCel = [];
      curCel = rangeValues[j][i];

      if(!(curCel === "")){
        msgObj[curCol].push(curCel)
        messString = JSON.stringify(msgObj);
        messExSheet.getRange(j, 1).setValue(messString); 
      }
     };
  };

}
```

Comment: You set messString to an new value in every iteration. Don't you mean something like `messString += JSON.stringify(msgObj);`? Also, what is the purpose of `msgObj[curCol].push(curCel)`, when you keep clearing it with `msgObj[curCol] = [];`?

Comment: @PalleDue

for 'msgObj[curCol] = [];' i need the current column to be the key name of the object

trying to achieve this result, in the below example the 'r1-c1' would be curCol.

var Row_1 = ['r1-c1', 'r1-c2', 'r1-c3'];
var Row_2 = ['r2-c1', 'r2-c2', 'r2-c3'];
var Row_3 = ['r3-c1', 'r3-c2', 'r3-c3'];

//Out put
[{"r1-c1":["r2-c1"]}, {"r1-c2":["r2-c2"]}, {"r1-c3":["r2-c3"]}]
[{"r1-c1":["r3-c1"]}, {"r1-c2":["r3-c2"]}, {"r1-c3":["r3-c3"]}]

Answer (score 1):

As per the code you shared, It is always setting last row, because you are resetting msgObj[curCol] for every iteration J.

```js
for ( i = 0; i < lastColumn; i++){ // columes ➔
    var curCol = rangeValues[0][i];
    msgObj[curCol] = [];

    for (j = 1 ; j < lastRow; j++){ // rows ⬇︎ //
      msgObj[curCol] = [];   <==================== This needs to be removed.
      curCel = [];
      curCel = rangeValues[j][i];

      if(!(curCel === "")){
        msgObj[curCol].push(curCel)
        messString = JSON.stringify(msgObj);
        messExSheet.getRange(j, 1).setValue(messString); 
      }
     };
  };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Allabakash,

If I remove that line how would I have an object with the key of the first-row column with the corresponding row number value?

Comment: Hi @JohnParrott, Since you are already initializing under i forloop, you dont need to do in j for loop. other wise it will reset for every j Value.

Comment: I opened another ticket and explained my goal in more detail with an example, here are the results https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61619795/storing-the-first-row-as-objectname-getting-coresponding-row-column-value/61624763#61624763